# How to ensure my Google Home Assistant application is not rejected?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

> During our testing, we were unable to complete at least one of the behaviors or actions advertised by your app. Please make sure that a user can complete all core conversational flows listed in your registration information or recommended by your app.
>
> Thank you for submitting your assistant app for review!
>
> During testing, your app was unable to complete a function detailed in the app’s description. The reviewer interacted with the app by saying: “how many iphones were sold in the UK?” and app replied “I didn't get that. Can you try with other question?" and left conversation.

How can I resolve the above point to approve my Google Assistant action skills?

[image]

Comment: Your question is incredibly vague. Although I've provided a few debugging tips below, we really need a lot more information about your Action before we can help. Dialogflow screen shots for Intents you think should be handling the phrase, code fragments that should be handling things, etc, can all be helpful.

Comment: Hey sorry for that here i added scree-shot of dialogflow intent setup.https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqLF5.png

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code in question or the intent you think should be handling this in Dialogflow, it is pretty difficult - but we can generalize.

It sounds like you have two issues:

1. Your fallback intent that generated the "I didn't get that" message is closing the conversation. This means that either the "close conversation" checkbox is checked in Dialogflow, you're using the `app.tell()` method when you should be using `app.ask()` instead, or the JSON you're sending back has close conversation set to true.
2. You don't have an intent to handle the question about how many iPhones were sold in the UK. This could be because you just don't list anything like that as a sample phrase, or the two parameters (the one for object type and the one for location) aren't using entity types that would match.

Comment: I'm using dialog-flow to setup intent and Entities, I checked the option "End conversation" in intents. I used fulfillment webhook to call api. Previously i opened conversion for further question but they rejected and gave this reason "the mic remains open without a prompt back to the user. Kindly consider either prompting the user with further options or closing the App at this point.". So i closed conversion after each question and answer and now they said conversion should not left. so i confused how i can resolve

Answer (score 1):

It means that somewhere, either in your app description or in a Dialogflow intent(they have full access to see what's in your intents) you hinted that “how many iphones were sold in the UK?” would be a valid question. Try changing the description/intents to properly match the restrictions of your app.

Comment: I'm using dialog-flow to setup intent and Entities, I checked the option "End conversation" in intents. I used fulfillment webhook to call api. Previously i opened conversion for further question but they rejected and gave this reason "the mic remains open without a prompt back to the user. Kindly consider either prompting the user with further options or closing the App at this point.". So i closed conversion after each question and answer and now they said conversion should not left. so i confused how i can resolve

Comment: If you "open the conversation for further questions" make sure you actually prompt the user. Basically they want every sentence your app sends to the user to end with something like: "Do you have any more questions?". Try to follow the guides for a right conversation flow, you wouldn't want the app to leave after each question when it still has more possibilities.

Comment: okay, programmatically how we can close the conversion? I'm using php api. is there any function to close the conversion after user say "no" for further question.

Comment: You could set a followup-no intent in Dialogflow and then select the end conversation checkbox there. Or use tell instead of ask in your code when you send the response.